# String.Format() -- Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Getting this error on the `String.Format()` method and have no idea why, everything looks good to me?

```
string fontface = "";

foreach(...)
{
  fontface = String.Format(@"{3}
    @font-face {
        font-family: '{0}';
        src: url('{0}.eot');
        src: url('{0}.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
                url('{0}.woff2') format('woff2'),
                url('{0}.woff') format('woff'),
                url('{0}.ttf') format('truetype'),
                url('{0}.svg#{0}') format('svg');
        font-weight:{1};
        font-style:{2};
    }"
  , family, weight, style, fontface);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to escape the `"{", "}"` by doubling them as `string.Format()` considers each `'{'` or `'}'` to be part of a placeholder (like `'{0}'`)

Something like this:

```
fontface = String.Format(@"{3}
    @font-face {{
        font-family: '{0}';
        src: url('{0}.eot');
        src: url('{0}.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
                url('{0}.woff2') format('woff2'),
                url('{0}.woff') format('woff'),
                url('{0}.ttf') format('truetype'),
                url('{0}.svg#{0}') format('svg');
        font-weight:{1};
        font-style:{2};
    }}"
  , family, weight, style, fontface);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your two problems are the lines `@font-face {` and `}"`. When using Format you have to escape curly braces by using two of them. Just change those to lines to `@font-face {{` and `}}"`

Comment: @ZeeTee, after `@font-face` you are using `{`